# Angular material cdk drag and drop, how to get target(mouse target) element?

Tags: angular-material, angular9, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I couldn't find any documentation on how to get the target of dropped element using cdk drag drop.
below is the sample code dragging item from **box1** div to **Shoppingbasket** div. here im expecting target should be **box2** div. but I'm receiving **Shoppingbasket** div.here is the
[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5t8a5k-vaxne2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html)

**HTML**

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>Available items</h2>
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" class="example-list" cdkDropListSortingDisabled
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div id="box1" class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of items" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example-container2">
    <h2>Shopping basket</h2>
    <div id="Shoppingbasket" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="basket" class="example-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div id="box2" class="example-box1" cdkDragHandle></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
   drop($event){
      if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex,event.currentIndex);
      } else {
         transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,event.container.data,event.previousIndex);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `event.target` in the cdk drag and drop events but you can manually add the attribute to the `event` object when needed like this :

```
event.target = event.container.element.nativeElement;
```